# Enable Annotator JS V2 only in some html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, annotatorjs

I'm trying to enable [Annotator Js](http://annotatorjs.org/) V2.0 only in some html elements and not the whole document without success. 
The [documentation](http://docs.annotatorjs.org/en/latest/api/ui.html) describes that a parameter can be passed as an option to define:

> the DOM element to which event listeners are bound. Defaults to
>   document.body, allowing annotation of the whole document.

So below is the code referred in the docs:

```
var app = new annotator.App();
app.include(annotator.ui.main, {element: document.body});
app.start();
```

I'm trying to define another html element by class name doing for example:

```
var app = new annotator.App();
app.include(annotator.ui.main, {element: '.class-name'});
app.start();
```

This is not working though. Can you advise on the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score -1):

I know its terribly late but hoping might help someone. :) Please use `document.querySelector` as shown below.

element: `document.querySelector('.class-name')`

Comment: Thanks Shyam, that's correct Annotator would be enabled in a particular element if this solution is used. However, unfortunately, when binding it to an element with a particular class name in a view where many elements share that same class name Annotator only works in the first element in the view. Have you found the same issue? 

    ``var app = new annotator.App();
    app.include(annotator.ui.main, { element: document.querySelector('.answer-content')
  });``